# List view fields pulled into visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is it possible to pull only the fields that are visible on an object list view into a visualforce page, dynamically? Rather that hardcoding each field, I'd like to just check which fields are present in the list view and pull them in. Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make a [REST API callout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_listviewdescribe.htm#!) to get List View describe information. The response key `columns` contains details of the column set.

You'll probably find it easier to use [Field Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm#!), if applicable to your situation.